# Error trying to convert x * y * 3 matrix to image in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, rgb

I have an x*y*3 matrix in MATLAB which I'm trying to convert to an image (layer one is the R intensity, layer 2 is the G intensity, layer 3 is the B intensity.

I'm currently only using an imwrite function to convert it, but the resulting image is always in black and white. Because my calculations all currently rely on the matrix being 3 layers I can't compress it down to one and use the ind2rgb function and the map, can I?

I'm pretty lost, so any advice would be greatly appreciated. Please and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the values of your image are out of range.

You can try either *uint8()*:

```
imwrite(uint8(I), 'file.png');
```

or, *mat2gray()*:

```
imwrite(mat2gray(I),'file.png');
```

assuming *I* is your image data.